# How to receive data from APNS feedback server in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, apple-push-notifications, feedback

Hello I'm trying to to something rather simple I think.
I have made an cocoa application that sends data using APNS, getting the tokens from my database, everything is set up and running perfect.

Now I want to check the APNS feedback server and remove any tokens received from my database.
I have found dozens of examples in php, javascript and so forth, but nothing in Objective C. I have read the programming guide from apple but can't figure out how to do it.

I am establishing a connection to APNS feedback but I don't know how to read the data.
I'm new to cocoa so please explain in detail :)

This is how I connect to the feedback server, it's the same way I connect when sending, just using another host.

```
- (void)connectToFeedBackServer
{
    if(self.certificate == nil)
    {
    return;
}

    NSString *feedBackHost = @"feedback.push.apple.com";
    const char *cHost = [feedBackHost UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"The size of cHost is: %lu", strlen(cHost));


    NSLog(@"Host is: %s", cHost);
// Define result variable.
OSStatus result;

// Establish connection to server.
PeerSpec peer;
result = MakeServerConnection(cHost, 2196, &socket, &peer);
    //NSLog(@"MakeServerConnection(): %d", result);

// Create new SSL context.
result = SSLNewContext(false, &context); //NSLog(@"SSLNewContext(): %d", result);

// Set callback functions for SSL context.
result = SSLSetIOFuncs(context, SocketRead, SocketWrite);
    // NSLog(@"SSLSetIOFuncs(): %d", result);

// Set SSL context connection.
result = SSLSetConnection(context, socket);
    // NSLog(@"SSLSetConnection(): %d", result);

// Set server domain name.
//result = SSLSetPeerDomainName(context, cHost, sizeof(cHost));
    NSLog(@"SSLSetPeerDomainName(): %d", result);
    result = SSLSetPeerDomainName(context, cHost, strlen(cHost));


    result = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(_theIdentity, &(certificate));

// Set client certificate.
CFArrayRef certificates = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)&_theIdentity, 1, NULL);
result = SSLSetCertificate(context, certificates);// NSLog(@"SSLSetCertificate(): %d", result);
CFRelease(certificates);

// Perform SSL handshake.
do 
    {
    result = SSLHandshake(context); NSLog(@"SSLHandshake(): %d", result);
} while(result == errSSLWouldBlock);
}
```

And how I try to read the data and save the received the tokens in an array

```
- (NSMutableArray *)CheckFeedBackServer
{
    char feedback[38];
    size_t feedBackSize = sizeof(feedback);
    size_t processed = 0;

    NSMutableData *feedbackData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSString *token = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *tokenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self connectToFeedBackServer];
    while ([self getSSLContext])
    {
        int bytesLength = SSLRead([self getSSLContext], &feedback, feedBackSize, &processed);

        [feedbackData appendBytes:feedback length:bytesLength];

        while ([feedbackData length] > 38)
        {
            NSData *deviceToken = [NSData dataWithBytes:[feedbackData bytes] + 6 length:32];

            token = [self deviceTokenToString:deviceToken];

            [tokenArray addObject:token];

            [feedbackData replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, 38) withBytes: "" length: 0];
        }
    }
    return tokenArray;
}

- (NSString *)deviceTokenToString: (NSData *)deviceToken;
{
    NSString *tmpToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    NSUInteger loc_begin = [tmpToken rangeOfString: @"<"].location+1;
    NSUInteger loc_end = [tmpToken rangeOfString: @">"].location-1;
    return [tmpToken substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(loc_begin, loc_end)];
}
```

Comment: Are you doing server programming in Objective-C? I think that's a little unusual. Can you post the code you're using for connecting to APNS to get the feedback?

Comment: I have editet my question and included the code

Comment: Feedback should be handled server side in APNS, not in your application. What do you want to achieve????

Comment: The application is a tool running on OSX to send PUSH messages to iOS devices not an app on the iOS device.. I want to get the stream data from APNS feedback server and tell my database to remove tokens.. But it is getting the tokens from the feedback server thats my problem.

Comment: `SSLRead()` returns `OSStatus` result, not `bytesLength`

Answer (score 2):

Just if anyone need to do something similar I solved my problem like this.

I use Apples ioSock class, and I have set the certificate in my code by calling the keychain

First I connect to the feedback server with this code

```
- (void)connectToFeedBackServer
{
    if(self.certificate == nil)
    {
    return;
}

    // Get the global variable feedbackHost and make it to a char
    const char *cHost = [feedbackHost UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"The size of cHost is: %lu", strlen(cHost));

    NSLog(@"Host is: %s", cHost);
    // Define result variable.
    OSStatus result;

    // Establish connection to server.
    PeerSpec peer;
    result = MakeServerConnection(cHost, 2196, &socket, &peer); 

    // Create new SSL context.
    result = SSLNewContext(false, &context); 

    // Set callback functions for SSL context.
    result = SSLSetIOFuncs(context, SocketRead, SocketWrite);

    // Set SSL context connection.
    result = SSLSetConnection(context, socket);

    // Set server domain name.
    result = SSLSetPeerDomainName(context, cHost, strlen(cHost));

    result = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(_theIdentity, &(certificate));

    // Set client certificate.
    CFArrayRef certificates = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)&_theIdentity, 1, NULL);
    result = SSLSetCertificate(context, certificates);
    CFRelease(certificates);

    do
    {
        result = SSLHandshake(context); NSLog(@"SSLHandshake(): %d", result);
    } while(result == errSSLWouldBlock);

}
```

And then I read the feedback data and add the tokens to an array, like this

```
- (NSMutableArray *)CheckFeedBackServer
{
    OSStatus result;

    NSMutableArray *feedbackTokens = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Retrieve message from SSL.
    size_t processed = 0;
    char buffer[38];
    do
    {
        // Fetch the next item
        result = SSLRead(context, buffer, 38, &processed);
        if (result) break;

        char *b = buffer;

        // Recover Device ID
        NSMutableString *deviceID = [NSMutableString string];
        b += 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            [deviceID appendFormat:@"%02x", (unsigned char)b[i]];
        }
        [feedbackTokens addObject:deviceID];

    } while (processed > 0);

    return feedbackTokens;
}
```